# Import Error Using Pycahrm IDE

Tags: pyqt, pycharm

I am newbie to Python GUI using Qt libraries, I started learning PyQt development in Pycharm IDE I tried to run code-- started showing

```
C:\Python27\python.exe C:/Users/xxxx/PycharmProjects/initproject/helloworld 12:58, hello world
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/xxxx/PycharmProjects/initproject/helloworld", line 4, in <module>
    from Pyside.QtCore import *
ImportError: No module named Pyside.QtCore

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I checked  project Interpreter(using python 2.7) and also checked for installed packages(pip, setuptools- i found Pyside) but still its showing Error. Please help and thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow :-)
Please look at [ask]
,  [mcve] and show what you've tried so far. This will help to get useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your mistake is simple: It is `PySide` and not `Pyside`. Try:

```
 from PySide.QtCore import *
```

All package names and objects are case-sensitive.

Comment: hi.. i tried as you said, but still showing same error. and also have tried a small example which pops up a small window using these imports:
import PyQt4
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui
still showing the same error

Comment: Well, wait a second: You said you were using `PySide` and not `PyQt4`. Do you have `PyQt4`installed?